# updating filtered mysql rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, filtered-lookup

I'm trying to update different rows from mysql that they filtered by some record . in this code first the user should enter two input : classnumber and level .
records that they have this fields will show in table then the user should be able to update this records information . but the problem is all of records are in one table in mysql so their id is different I mean for example the first record that match with two inputs id is 2 and then the next one is 5 and next one 6 and ....

with this kind of situation how should I change the code below ?

```
<form id="searchform" method="post" dir="rtl" action=""> 
 level :<input name="level"  style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:6px;font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" id="level" />
 classnumber :<input name="classnum"  style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:6px;font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" id="classnum" />
 <input style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:120px; font-size: 14px;  padding: 5px 14px;" type="submit" value="جستجو" name="enter"   />
</form>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
  $sql="SELECT * FROM  `".$tbl_name."` where classnum='".$_REQUEST['classnum']."' and level='".$_REQUEST['level']."' ";
  $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
 }
?>

<div class="cleaner h30"></div>
<br>

 <form name="form1" action="" method="POST">
  <center>
   <div>                                
    <div align="center" width = 615>
    <table class="stats" cellspacing="0" width="615" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="20" scope="col" >Id</th>
     <th width="60" scope="col">Name</th>
     <th width="60" scope="col">Last Name</th>
     <th width="42" scope="col">Midterm</th>    
     <th width="54" scope="col">Class mark</th>
     <th width="42" scope="col">Final Quiz</th>
     <th width="54" scope="col">State</th>
     <th width="54" scope="col">Details</th>
    </tr>
                                            <?php
      while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $id[]=$rows['id'];
    ?>
                                        <tr>
      <td align="center">
     <input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"  style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 10px;"></td>
      <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 60px;" type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value= "<? echo $rows['name']; ?>"  /></td>
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 60px;" type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname" value= "<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>"  /></td> 
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" name="midmark[]" id="midmark" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" name="classmark[]" id="classmark" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" name="finalmark[]" id="finalmark" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" name="state[]" id="state" /></td>
     <td align="center"><input style=" font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;  padding: 5px; width: 50px;" type="text" name="details[]" id="details"  /></td>
    </tr>

     <?php
                                         }
                                         ?>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
    </div>
   </center>
   <input style="margin-top:10px; float:right; margin-right:175px; font-size: 14px;  padding: 5px 14px;" type="submit" value="ثبت" name="Submit"   />
  </form>

<?php
 // Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
  {
   for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    $sql1=mysql_query(" UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET midmark='".$_REQUEST['midmark'][$i]."' , classmark='".$_REQUEST['classmark'][$i]."' , finalmark='".$_REQUEST['finalmark'][$i]."' , state='".$_REQUEST['state'][$i]."' , details='".$_REQUEST['details'][$i]."'  WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id'][$i]."' ");                           $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
   }

if($result1){
 header("location:results.php");
  }
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: also - highly recommend you create a css style rather than declaring it inline. Makes your code more readable and much easier to maintain

Comment: thanks for advice but this is for testing it's not the original version of code . any one can tell me how can i do this process ?